# Flex / ZendAMF / PHP app, corrupted data with some linux clients problem

Tags: php, mysql

i'm buiding a survey web application, using Flex for the front-end (nice forms), and a MySQL database for the storage, linked by PHP with the help of ZendAMF.

I largely borrowed from this nice tutorial by Alan Gruskoff :
http://digitalshowcase.biz/wordpress/?page_id=26
(The only one tutorial i've found to work with the last version of Flex).

The app seems to works nicely in my tests, except on certain linux boxes : the data is somehow corrupted : there is no error message, no glitch, but the response of the forms are not what the user selected.

I tried to reproduce the error on a fresh installed ubuntu VM, but it works fine. I've asked friends for some tests, and several linux users showed the same problem, on ubuntu and suse machines, all freshly updated and functionnal.

The application was targeted to be the survey tool for my doctoral thesis, so i'm quite desperate here, and before i'm dumping it to start anew with php only, i'm asking here in case someone can help, thanks :-)

Please excuse my english, by the way.

LJ.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, i'm sorry it was a very dumb error. I was fooled by the client-side complexity, and the testing seemed to point a linux client problem, but it was a type mismatch on the database.

I needed more testing, with a more focused procedure :)